# Can a single electron have a quantized orbital angular momentum in the direction of propagation in free space?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, reference-frames, electrons, discrete

I trying to understand the [article](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.99.190404) about quantized orbital angular momentum in electron vortex beams. The article is not important per se, as there are many others. But I'm reading it as if an electron in free space may have quantized orbital angular momentum, yet the experiments are done with a beam (packets) of electrons.

My question is, can we have experimentally, a single electron with quantized angular momentum in the direction of propagation in free space or are there other constraints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a single electron can have angular momentum in free space.

> Electrons can also possess quantized canonical orbital angular momentum which
>   does not depend on the presence of a magnetic field.  This is well known in the case of
>   bound states in atoms and quantum dots [6], in which there is a confining potential,
>   however recently it was discovered that
>   free
>   electrons can be imprinted with orbital
>   angular  momentum.
>
> In this paper, we show that the total orbital angular momentum of the electron
>   is  described  by  the  parallel  axis  theorem.   This  angular  momentum  comprises  the
>   canonical and diamagnetic components,  which are associated with rotation relative
>   to  the  centre  of  mass  of  the  wavefunction,  and  a  cyclotron  component  which  has
>   expectation value equal to that for the classical orbit.  Interestingly, for free electrons
>   all  three  of  these  components  can  have  similar  magnitude.

Quoted from [Parallel axis theorem for free-space electron wavefunctions, Greenshields et al., 2015](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.08702).

Comment: Please link to arxiv abstract pages, rather than to PDF files.

Comment: To get this straight, because I'm just getting textual paragraphs of confusing papers from everyone I ask. Let me see if I understand it correctly, you take Schrödinger equation for a free particle and write it in cylindrical coordinates. In this frame, the base solutions include a $e^{im_z}$, if I measure (somehow) the L_z of an electron I would get some m_z, that's it, right?

Comment: If you mean "Here (
r,φ
) are polar coordinates in the (
x,y
) plane,
whereas
l
= 0
,
±
1
,
±
2
,...
and
m
,
n
= 0
,
1
,
2
,...
are the
quantum numbers corresponding to the azymuthal, ra-
dial, and longitudinal directions"

Comment: And "Owing to this,
the solutions (2) have a well-defined
z
-component of the
OAM. Indeed,
ˆ
L
z
|
u
l,
m
,
n
〉
=
~
l
|
u
l,
m
,
n
〉
(
ˆ
L
z
=
−
i
~
∂/∂φ
),
and, effectively, the electron possesses an
intrinsic angu-
lar  momentum
L
≡
~
l
=
~
l
e
z
.  "

Comment: And you mean m_z the OAM then yes I think you are correct. Do you mean m_z the OAM?